# ¿Cómo redirigir usuarios desde un login con PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy intentando redirigir usuarios desde un login y me saltan 2 errores que no se cómo solucionar (estoy empezando con php, mi idea mas adelante es redirigir según el rol de cada usuario, por ahora solo redirigir).

**HTML con el form:**

```
<form method="post" action="login.php" class="col m6 s12 offset-m3">

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label for="user">Usuario</label>
                            <input name="user" id="user" type="text" 
                       class="validate">
                        </div>
                    </p>
                    <p>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                            <input name="password" id="password" 
                             type="password" class="validate">
                        </div>

                    </p>

                    <p 
                        class="row checkbox">
                        <label class="col l4 m6 s9">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span>Recordarme</span>
                        </label>
                    </p>
                    
                    <br><br/>
                    <button name="button" id="button" class= "btn-large col s6 teal lighten-1 waves-effect waves-green" type="submit">Ingresar</button>
                    <br><br/>
                    <br><br/>
            </form>
```

**PHP con el login:**

```
    <?php

$connection = mysqli_connect(
            "localhost",
            "root",
            "",
            "Proyecto"
);


$user = $_POST['Nombre'];
$password = md5($_POST['Contraseña']);

$select = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios
            WHERE Nombre = '$user'
            and Contraseña = '$password'";

$select_ex = mysqli_query($connection, $select);

 if($select_ex == false){
     echo "Error $select";
 }
 else {
     $total = mysqli_num_rows($select_ex);

     if($total === 1) {

        $reg = mysqli_fetch_array($select_ex);
        
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $reg['Id_user'];

        // Redirección
        header("location: dTecnica.php");
     }
     else {
         echo "nonop";
     }
 } ?>
```

**Mi tabla Usuarios de mysql:**

```
Id_user int (10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
Nombre varchar(50),
Contraseña varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

**Errores:**

> **Notice**: Undefined index: Nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\login.php on line 11
>
> **Notice**: Undefined index: Contraseña in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\login.php on line 12
> Error SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Nombre = '' and Contraseña = 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'

No se de donde sale eso de Contraseña = 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e' alguien me podría ayudar? Muchas gracias.

Comment: primer cosa que veo, donde recibes los valores de este modo: `$_POST['Nombre']` no estas colocando el nombre de la etiqueta name que tienes en el html, por que si revisas por ejemplo para el nombre la etiqueta que deberías tener ahi es: `user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error se localiza en estas dos líneas:

```
$user = $_POST['Nombre'];
$password = md5($_POST['Contraseña']);
```

La razón, cuando vas a leer los valores que fueron tecleados en dichas cajas de texto pero en PHP, debes colocar el nombre de la etiqueta `name` que tiene declarado; es decir tu código debería estar de este modo

```
$user = $_POST["user"];
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);
```

Por otro lado también estas cometiendo el error de querer utilizar caracteres especiales como la `ñ` de tu columna `contraseña` omitelo; dejalo como contrasenia tal vez pues esto a la larga te va a causar errores e inconsistencias *ni acentos ni uso de ñ o diéresis*

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Exactamente esos fueron mis 2 errores, pensaba que dentro de los [] del $_post iban los nombres de las variables de la base de datos. Por otro lado el caracter ñ me estaba impidiendo que valide la contraseña. Gracias nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, claramente php indica que los indices entregados por el POST no existen.

Según la declaración de tu FORM, tienes dos campos, un "user" y un "password", por ende, en tu PHP debes recibirlos de la misma forma.

`$user = $_POST['user'];`

`$password = md5($_POST['password']);`

Saludos.

http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Deberías considerar proporcionarle el enlace de la documentación donde se indica claramente la sintaxis de `POST`.